# MSBuild target failing on server, yet succeeding locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild, csproj

For our web project, I require the assembly version of the project to version our static content.

I have declared a target in the web project file to get the assembly identity and retrieve the version number from it, like:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <IvanhoWebVersion>
    </IvanhoWebVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="SetIvanhoWebVersion" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="-----------------">
    </Message>
    <Message Text="Entering target SetIvanhoWebVersion">
    </Message>
    <Message Text="-----------------">
    </Message>
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyIdentities" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <CreateProperty value="%(AssemblyIdentities.Version)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="IvanhoWebVersion" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <Message Text="Assembly version = v$(IvanhoWebVersion)">
    </Message>
    <Exec Command=" &quot;$(SolutionDir)Ivanho.Lib\TranslationGenerator\TranslationGenerator.exe&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)Areas\UI\Static\locales\translationsrc\Translations-EN-NL-AR.xlsx&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)Areas\UI\Static\locales\v.$(IvanhoWebVersion)&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

This works like a charm when building locally, however when trying to check this in to our TFS build server it fails with the following error:

> Cannot get assembly name for "bin\Ivanho.Web.dll". Could not load file
>   or assembly 'Ivanho.Web.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the path specified.

This error is thrown at the same line of the `GetAssemblyIdentity` call.

I can't figure out why this isn't working on the build server, I'm pretty new to MSBuild, can someone point me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Either the file is not there or the path to it is wrong. 
Have a look on the build server to see if the file's there. You can use the converttoabsolutepath task to be certain of the paths see:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882668(v=vs.100).aspx. You could put in an error statement to check for the file e.g.

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll')" Text="FileNotFound"/>
```